# How to append multiple images to the span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert multiple images in the span element dynamically when I read number from the database.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "all_data.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            for (var i = 0, len = response.data.length; i < len; i++) {
            $('.item_holder').append('<span class="rating_images">'+response.data[i].number+'</span>');
        }
        }
    });
```

I need to check what number is in the variable `response.data[i].number` and then insert 
`<img class="rating_img" src="../images/star.png" alt="rating"/>` x number of times depending on that number

I know how to check the value but I don't know how to insert in multiple times in this inline text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have understood your problem correctly, but maybe something like that? :

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    var number = response.data[i].number;
    var images = "";

    for(var j = 0; j < number; j++)
        images += '<img class="rating_img" src="../images/star.png" alt="rating"/>';

    $('.item_holder').append('<span class="rating_images">'+ images +'</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "all_data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        var star_html = '<img class="rating_img" src="../images/star.png" alt="rating"/>';
        var make_stars = function(rating){
            var tpl = '';
            for(i=0; i<rating; i++){
                tpl += star_html;
            }
            return tpl;
        };

        $.each(response.data, function(){
            $('.item_holder').append('<span class="rating_images">'+make_stars(response.data[i].number)+'</span>');                
        });            
    }
});
```